# Перенаправление английской версии сайта (Joomla) на другой домен

Tags: joomla, редирект

Есть сайт на Joomla 3.9.21. На нем русская и английская версия сайта. Русская работает на основном домене (site.ru), английская на (site.ru/en).
Как настроить переадресацию английской версии на site.com вместо site.ru/en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте файл .htaccess. Пропишите в нём нужные правила переадресации.

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]